# Is there any way to use RMI or SOAP instead of REST in Spring Cloud Foundry?

Tags: soa, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

Since we are in banking industrial and all provided web services are based on RMI or SOAP (because API is important in financial services), So is there any way to use RMI or SOAP in Spring Cloud?

I used Spring Cloud for a public service application with REST API already but now I'm hesitated to use rest for banking system.

Indeed, there lie two question

- Is it recommended using rest in financial services?
- Does Spring Cloud support RMI or SOAP web service?

Comment: Some clarification would help, Spring Cloud and Cloud Foundry are separate things. Spring Cloud is available on Cloud Foundry as Spring Cloud Services (SCS). If you are using SCS you should talk to your support contact. Spring Cloud is agnostic of your service implementation. Whatever is supported by Spring Boot and Spring Framework is a possibility. I don't think the community can answer "Is it recommended using rest in financial services".

Comment: _Whatever is supported by Spring Boot and Spring Framework is a possibility_ By your advice Spring supports RMI and too provides RmiServiceExporter class to expose a bean as a RMI service. My question is that Does Eureka or any load balanacer support RMI?

Answer (score 1):

Microservice Showdown – REST vs SOAP vs Apache Thrift (And Why It Matters) [enter link description here](http://nordicapis.com/microservice-showdown-rest-vs-soap-vs-apache-thrift-and-why-it-matters/)

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge and experience, there aren't great differents between REST APIs and SOAP APIs in terms of security: the only difference is about integration (SOAP provides the wsdl that allows a minimal client to be generated starting from it) and 'heaviness' (REST APIs have generally less overhead than SOAP in terms of content to send)

For security needs, using HTTPS is allowed on both REST and SOAP

Comment: As you know SOAP and RMI have a clear contract in API that can be helpful for consumers

Comment: This is what I mean with 'integration'